# Handshaking Lemma and existence of the graph

Tags: graph-theory

Handshaking lemma in graph theory basically says that The degree sum is equal to twice the number of edges.

The doubt I have is, does this condition enough to prove the existence of the graph. 
That is if the degree sum is even then a graph exists with that corresponding degree sequence.

**This may not be true when the simple graphs are considered. But what if we allow loops and multiple edges**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, per [David Eppstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:David_Eppstein)'s contribution to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_(graph_theory)#Degree_sequence):

> The construction of such a graph is straightforward: connect vertices with odd degrees in pairs by a matching, and fill out the remaining even degree counts by self-loops.

Comment: Ah thank you. So you mean we can connect the odd number of vertices as far as possible and since the difference of two odd numbers is an even number we can fill out the remaining degrees with loops ?

Comment: Even simpler, each odd-degree vertex needs only a single edge to another vertex, plus some self-loops. This works since the difference between an odd number *and $1$* is an even number.

Comment: Ah. YES indeed!. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Chris Culter has your answer when (multiple) loops are allowed.

For simple graphs, you can use the [Havel–Hakimi algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Havel%E2%80%93Hakimi_algorithm) to establish whether a given set of vertex degree values - a degree sequence - corresponds to a graph.

The process is that you sort the degree sequence descending then generate a new sequence by removing a highest-degree node of degree $d$ and subtract one off  each of the following $d$ degree values, to produce a new shorter sequence.

The process can be applied repeatedly until you reach a sequence that is trivial to recognize as possible or impossible. (In principle, for a [graphical sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_(graph_theory)#Degree_sequence) - one that corresponds to a realizable graph - this process can be continued to finish with all zeroes).

Working a sample degree sequence:

$\begin{array}{c}
&3&3&3&3&2\\
&&2&2&2&2\\
&&&1&1&2\\
\text{re-sort}&&&2&1&1\\
&&&&0&0&\checkmark \\
\end{array}$

Comment: Thats an interesting algorithm. Thank you